# How to test for an application in a makefile

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements

As part of my project I'm creating a graph over the dependencies of the different modules.

```
dependency-graph.png: dependency-graph.txt
        dot -Tpng $< -o $@
```

This rule assumes the existence of the program 'dot' (graphiviz package).
I do not wish to force my collaborators to install 'dot' if they do not want to,
so how do I make the above mentioned rule only active then 'dot' is installed?

The closet I have come is the following

```
GRAPH_PROGRAM = dot
PATH_DOT := $(type -p $(GRAPH_PROGRAM))
dependency-graph.png: dependency-graph.txt
ifneq (,$(findstring  $(GRAPH_PROGRAM),$(PATH_DOT)))
     $(GRAPH_PROGRAM) -Tpng $< -o $@
else
    -@echo "The program '$(GRAPH_PROGRAM)' is not installed,"
    -@echo "so no graphics will be produced"
    -@echo "Please install it using:"
    -@echo "   sudo apt-get install graphviz"
endif
```

but it only prints the 'else' message. I suspect i'm using the construct

```
PATH_DOT := $(type -p $(GRAPH_PROGRAM))
```

wrongly, since i get the correct result if is instead put in

```
PATH_DOT := "/usr/bin/dot"
```

or

```
PATH_DOT := ""
```

Comment: Show us what you tried, because what you need to know is: Why didn't *that* work? Put it in the post.

Comment: The part of the makefile we need to see, you didn't provide: you show how `dependency-graph.png` is used as a target, but the important thing is how it's used as a prerequisite: _that's_ what you need to change.  Having the rule there doesn't hurt if it's never invoked, and without `dot` they can't create it, so you need to ensure it's not a prerequisite of anything if it doesn't exist.

Comment: SO much for trying to create a minimal example. Extending it now.

Answer (score 0):

The below rule will create graphs provided that dot is in the PATH:

```
dependency-graph.png: dependency-graph.txt
        type -p dot && dot -Tpng $< -o $@
```